# How to transform a column with 3 possible values into 3 columns with 0 if the value is absent and 1 if it is present

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe :

|  | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | abc | x |
| 2 | A | abc | y |
| 3 | A | abc | z |
| 4 | B | bcd | x |
| 5 | B | bcd | z |
| 6 | C | cde | x |
| 7 | D | def | y |

and this is what I want :

|  | col_1 | col_2 | col_x | col_y | col_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | abc | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | B | bcd | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | C | cde | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | D | def | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I try with df.pivot but I don't known how insert 0 and 1 and how to drop unused rows at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to execute a `pd.get_dummies` before grouping:

```py
(pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col_3'], prefix='col')
   .groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'], as_index = False)
   .sum()
)
  col_1 col_2  col_x  col_y  col_z
0     A   abc      1      1      1
1     B   bcd      1      0      1
2     C   cde      1      0      0
3     D   def      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and then [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) for only `0, 1` values if duplicates in data. If no duplicates is possible remove `clip`:

```
df = (pd.crosstab([df['col_1'], df['col_2']], df['col_3'])
        .add_prefix('col_')
        .clip(upper=1)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  col_1 col_2  col_x  col_y  col_z
0     A   abc      1      1      1
1     B   bcd      1      0      1
2     C   cde      1      0      0
3     D   def      0      1      0
```